# How do I use Ember.sendEvent to send an event to every instantiated controller

Tags: javascript, events, ember.js, controller, routes

I have an action in my application route that causes a global change to occur.  This global change involves some asynchronous processing (promises), which, when settled requires me to send an event to my instantiated controllers. Controllers listening for the event will need to refresh some views.

More specifically, I'm downloading some fonts and any controller with a canvas view needs be repainted.

I know which controllers have a canvas.  Using `controllerFor` will instantiate the controller if it does not already exist, which is bad. Likewise, `__container__.lookup` does the same.

If this design is crap let me know.  But otherwise, how do I get the instantiated controllers?

Also, the fonts can not be pre-loaded because they are humongous (5MB each).  Instead, we are using a service that sends fonts containing only the characters we request. If the user types additional characters, we have to request a new font.

Comment: Thinking about filtering through  Em.keys(App.__container__.cache.dict), but it feels so dirty!

Comment: I'm also not sure how to get the App instance in an ember-cli project, aside from assuming the global variable.  It all feels so dirty, which is why I question the design of this.  I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the application route, this code works to get all the instantiated controllers.  Feels dirty, however, so I'm holding out for a better answer.

```
controllers: function() {
  var conatiner, regex;

  container = this.get("container");
  regex = /^controller:/;

  return Ember.keys(container.cache.dict).filter(function(key) {
    return key.match(regex);
  }).map(function(key) {
    return container.lookup(key);
  });
}.property().volatile().readOnly(),

triggerEvent: function() {
  this.get("controllers").forEach(function(controller) {
    Ember.sendEvent(controller, "didLoadFont");
  });
}
```